# Object has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a few DOM elements dynamically like,

```
var anchorElement = jQuery('<a />',{text:property.text});
var liElement = jQuery('<li />',{"class":"navlink_"+i,id:"navlink_"+i});
anchorElement.on('click',property.fnctn);
liElement.append(anchorElement);
parentID.append(liElement);
```

Where `property` is a JSON object.
`property.text` is the text that I want to put into anchor element. (Works fine)

I want to attach a click event handler to that anchor element.
The function that needs to be bound to that element is specified in JSON and we can access it like

```
property.fnctn
```

The following line should bind the event handler to the anchor element.

```
anchorElement.on('click',property.fnctn);
```

This was not working so I tried converting it into string like,

```
anchorElement.on('click',property.fnctn.toString());
```

No Success...

When I click on this link, the error is logged in the console

The object  has no method 'apply'.
What is the reason...???

I am able to get it working with a slight work around like

```
anchorElement.attr('onclick',property.fnctn+"()");
```

Above statement works, but I want to know why `.on()` API is not working.

Thanks :)
AÐitya.

Comment: What's the value of `property.fnctn`?

Comment: Its a string...

I have defined a few functions, names of the respective functions are in property.fnctn

I am iterating over JSON array, so every time there is new value..

This is the JSON structure

{"item1":{"text":"Wallet","fnctn":"walletClick"}},
                            {"item2":{"text":"Pay Someone","fnctn":"paySomeoneClick"}},
                            {"item3":{"text":"Pay Bills","fnctn":"payBillsClick"}}

Comment: A string containing what? The name of a function or the definition for a function?

Comment: @AdityaParab: A *string*?! Don't use strings to hook up event handlers, use functions.

Comment: Name of a function...
Sorry I was not aware of shift + enter for new line :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He said it was in a JSON object, which made me curious. I'm by no means an expert but I didn't think a JSON property could be an actual function.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: It can't be, but that doesn't mean you should use a string for an event handler. Just that you need to do a bit more work. :-)

Comment: @T.J.

The function that needs to be invoked will different every time.. So I am getting the appropriate function name from server in JSON format...

Comment: and I want to bind "that" function every time the script is run..

Comment: @AdityaParab: I would recommend refactoring that (using a parameter instead, for instance), but I've updated my answer to work with what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**:

Youve said that `property.actfn` is a string, `"paySomeoneClick"`. It's best not to use strings for event handlers, use *functions* instead. If you want the function `paySomeoneClick`, defined in the string, to be called, and if that function is global, you can do this:

```
anchorElement.on('click',function(event) {
    return window[property.fnctn](event);
});
```

That works because global functions are properties of the global object, which is available via `window` on browsers, and because of the bracketed notation described below.

If the function is on an object you have a reference to, then:

```
anchorElement.on('click',function(event) {
    return theObject[property.fnctn](event);
});
```

That works because in JavaScript, you can access properties of objects in two ways: Dotted notation with a literal property name (`foo.bar` accesses the `bar` propety on `foo`) and bracketed notation with a string property name (`foo["bar"]`). They're equivalent, except of course in the bracketed notation, the string can be the result of an expression, including coming from a property value like `property.fnctn`.

But I would recommend stepping back and refactoring a bit so you're not passing function names around in strings. *Sometimes* it's the right answer, but in my experience, not often. :-)

**Original answer**:

*(This assumed that `property.fnctn` was a function, not a string. But may be of some use to someone...)*

The code

```
anchorElement.on('click',property.fnctn);
```

will attach the function to the event, but during the call to the function, `this` will refer to the DOM element, *not* to your `property` object.

To get around that, use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
anchorElement.on('click',$.proxy(property.fnctn, property));
```

...or ES5's [`Function#bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
anchorElement.on('click',property.fnctn.bind(property));
```

...or a closure:

```
anchorElement.on('click',function(event) {
    return property.fnctn(event);
});
```

More reading (on my blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Thanks T.J !
Got it loud and clear...

May be I need to talk with my project manager to consider redesigning this approach... :)

Alright, is there any reason as why not to use strings as event handlers? (Just curious about it)

Comment: @AdityaParab: Re using strings to assign to `click` handlers, it's not a good idea because it requires the JavaScript parser to fire up and parse the string, and it obscures what's going on. Re passing function names around, it conflates *code* and *data*, which is usually (but not always!) less than ideal. If you can abstract that a bit, pass around information that your code then interprets to say "oh, that means we should call this function", it's usually best. But there can be real arguments for just passing a function name around, when server code is sending client code a message. Best,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay Thanks for reply.. sure u can delete it. do u hav any reference to help me?