# Supplying a callback to Jeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jeditable, jquery-callback

**Summary:** When I try supplying a `onsubmit` or `onreset` callback to Jeditable, I get `Object [function] has no method 'apply'` errors.

**How I got here:** I've been working on [a rails plugin to supply Jeditable and jWYSIWYG](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails) for in-place WYSIWYG editing. Development is driven by a Rails project I'm working on which asks for specific functions.

One of the options I added was the ability to trigger Jeditable's edit mode using a button instead of clicking on the editable text itself, following the pattern suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11955863/306084). The next step, though, is to hide the button while in edit mode, and reveal it again when leaving edit mode.

The hide is easy enough; I just added a line to the triggering function which sends `.toggle()` to the button. Reveal is trickier. I figure I need to `.toggle()` again on submit or cancel, and helpfully, Jeditable offers `onsubmit` and `onreset` callbacks.

However, when I try using those callbacks, I get this `Object [something] has no method 'apply'` errors.

**What I'm trying:** Because this is in the context of a Rails helper, the actual mechanics are a little more involved than this, but the upshot is that I'm trying to follow [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189758/306084), handing Jeditable this in the args:

```
"onsubmit":"showTrigger",
```

and then including this script:

```
function showTrigger(settings, original) {
    $(".edit_trigger[id='element_id']").toggle();
}
```

However, on submitting changes or canceling an edit, I get the error

```
Object showTrigger has no method 'apply'
```

...as described above.

I also tried sending in a function directly as the `"onsubmit"` argument (i.e. `"onsubmit": "function(settings, original){$(\".edit_trigger[id='element_id']\").toggle();}"` and then I just get `Object function(settings, original){$(\".edit_trigger[id='element_id']\").toggle();} has no method 'apply'` instead.

There must be something wrong with how I'm handing in this callback. Any ideas?

ETA: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11666349/306084) suggests to me that somehow I'm providing a string to Jeditable when it expects a function instead. However, because I'm working within the context of a Rails helper, I'm not at all sure how to fix that - the `"showTrigger"` bit is set as a Ruby variable in the helper, and although `window.showTrigger()` is defined when the window is loaded, I don't know how to designate that function within a Ruby variable such that it will be recognized as a function at page load time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my ETA above suggested, the problem did turn out to be passing a string rather than a function. My Rails helper was generating arguments for Jeditable by taking an argument hash and using `.to_json`. This made the string function name into, well, a quoted string. In order to provide this argument as a function name Jeditable would understand, I needed to include these specific arguments as a pre-JSON-ified argument.

In other words, instead of defining a Ruby variable which contained a string with the name of the function, I defined it containing the JSON object with the name of the function. Instead of `trigger_reset = 'showTrigger'` I used `trigger_reset = '{ onsave: showTrigger, onreset: showTrigger }'`.

Then, instead of including this as another argument in the `args` hash, where that hash was added to the `args` object in JS using `$().extend()`, I added the value of the `trigger_reset` variable as a third argument to `extend()`.

Of course, this turns out to all be bound up in code I didn't include in my original question, so it's no wonder nobody could help. Sorry, and thanks anyway.