# Convert String to Function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am trying to convert strings to AngularJS Service method calls in a controller.  For example, I would like to convert the string "Contact.send(email)" to call an existing service method.  I thought to use:

`window["Contact"]["send"](email);`

as in this thread - [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string?lq=1) - but it says that the Contact service is undefined, despite being injected into the controller.

Comment: Have you tried something like `eval("contact.send(email)");`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid using eval, if at all possible.

Comment: I ran into similar problem back in the day. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666301/object-has-no-method-apply

Comment: We need more code to go on. Why are you trying to reference `Contact` on `window` if it was injected into your controller? Post your controller and the service returning `Contact` please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use $injector to get a service from a string:

```
$injector.get('Contact')['send'](email);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the $scope.$eval method to evaluate an expression on the current $scope context.

`$scope.$eval("Contact.send(email)");`

but you need to make sure that the Contact object is available on the $scope object, else it would not work. See scope documentation for this https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: How could I pass the email argument, unless assign it into the scope?

Comment: Yes everything is evaluated in context of the scope only. If need to pass email argument either add it to scope or use the acual email such as `send('mymail@test.com')`